# Django Rest Framework + Swagger : error { "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect." }

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

Hello I am using Django Rest Framework along with Swagger. I am getting this error upon POST request.

```
{
  "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
}
```

This is quite strange considering the POST request contains

```
"X-CSRFToken: 01658Gyfzlhz2v6zgoZjtbHSrWzrVTBrlseyp2JMfVHvh6PzfamHpgxuh4eaVXad"
```

This is the complete request

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/order-post/" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H  "X-CSRFToken: 01658Gyfzlhz2v6zgoZjtbHSrWzrVTBrlseyp2JMfVHvh6PzfamHpgxuh4eaVXad" -d "customer_name=Muhammad%20Ahsan%20Mukhtar&country=Pakistan&address=Cb%20679%20Kashmir%20Colony%20Gujranwala%20Cantt&email=ahsan44411%40gamil.com&postal_code=52250&country_code=4343&phone_number=243434&tracking_number=4343"
```

I have even tried using csrf_exempt but that does not help either, I get the same error.

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name="dispatch")
class OrderPost(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
```

I am using the default settings for Django Rest Framework which is SessionAuthentication I believe.

I've been stuck on this for hours without luck, any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: DRF views are already exempted from csrf checks

Comment: @JPG this still does not example the error I am getting

Comment: Have you tried to access the end-point without sending `X-CSRFToken` header?

Comment: @JPG Im not sending X-CSRFToken. Swagger is probably adding this header itself. I've tested the API on Postman, it works fine over there. It's only giving an issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a similar issue. It turns out the SessionAuthentication in the DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS was causing the issue. Try removing or commenting that line.

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication'
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
       'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
       'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
       'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ],
}
```